# A question on co-ordinates of intersecting lines...Given in picture below

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

[image: CO]

Please do also MENTION how you got the solution.........

Comment: If you provide us with information on what you have tried perhaps someone can provide a hint or answer that is based upon your work. Such hints or answers are often more useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A(-3,5),B(6,-7)$. Also let $C(p,q),D(s,t)$ be the points you want.

Then, they satisfy the following :

$$\vec{AC}=(1/3)\vec{AB}\iff (p-(-3),q-5)=(1/3)(6-(-3),-7-5),$$
$$\vec{AD}=(2/3)\vec{AB}\iff (s-(-3),t-5)=(2/3)(6-(-3),-7-5).$$
Then, you can find $p,q,r,s$.

Comment: Would you please explain... further I'm just in school................THanks for answering

Comment: OK. Do you know vector?

Comment: A little bit I know of what I studied in Physics ..

Comment: OK. Draw the line segment $ACDB$. $A, B$ are the end points and $C,D$ are on the line ($C$ is near to $A$). Then, $\vec{AC}=(1/3)\vec{AB}$ means $A,C,B$ are on a line and the length of $AC$ is $1/3$ of the length of $AB$. Do you think you can solve the equations I wrote?

Comment: I'm working on it

Comment: Can you give me a link of an image or explain what is a trisecting line..?? I have only heard of bisecting lines.... Sorry to sound so stupid.....

Comment: You can google it. If you have three points $A(0,0),B(1,0),C(2,0),D(3,0)$, then $B,C$ are the points which trisectthe line segment $AD.$ By the way, did you get the answer $A$?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/bCx0C.jpg  Here's what I did.......

Comment: one mistake. $-7-5=-12$, not $-15.$ Then, you'll get $p=0, q=1.$

Comment: OH Yeah!! I finally got IT!!!! Thank you so much for being patient and helping me every step!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Great! My pleasure!

Comment: Just ONE more thing...NEXT time a similar question comes what should I do WHich BASIC formula did you use....?? in which I can substitute the coordinates

Comment: Yes, you can. Also, drawing the figures helps.

Answer (score 0):

A=(-3,5)    B=(6,-7)

Delta X = 6-(-3) = 9 and so the trisection points are 9/3 = +3
Delta Y = -7-5 = -12 and so the trisection points are -12/3 = -4.

so just add these to the A co-ordinate to get the points

First trisection point = -3 + 3,5+(-4) = 0,1
Second trisection point is got from the first one by adding the deltas
0,1 + 3,-4 = 3,-3

so the answers are (0,1) and (3,-3) which is answer A.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, since I see coordinates which are of form $0,y$ or $x,0$ I would prefer to take out the equation of the line and put the values.

$9(y-5)=-12(x+3)$
So the equation is $12x+9y-9=0$ or $4x+3y-3=0$

Putting x=0, y=1.
So (0,1) satisfies the line. 
Also, (3,-3) satisfies it too. 
(A) option is correct.

Comment: Please tell me the original formula you used .... Since this is the first time I am solving such problems....